# Can I run my Java source code having only mapper class (Source code without Reducer Class) over Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I create only `mapper class` into source code..

```
import ...
class mainClass {

class myMapper extends Mapper<Input and Output Pairs> {
      //body of mapper
    }
} // end of mainClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You have 2 options:-

If you set 0 as reducer than your job will call map only. However, your map output will not be sorted.

If you need sorted output of your map phase you can do not need aggregation you can go for identity reducer.

Comment: That is not true Jack, if you set the number of reducer to 0 then the map outputs will be stored. You need to set your output configurations in the same way than with a reducer. In that case your output files will start with the **part-m** prefix instead with **part-r** (m for mapper and r for reducer), assuming textoutputformat.

Comment: @Rojo: If I Set the numberofReducer to 0 then I dont need to specify reducer class. Seems like thats what he is asking.. further information:- http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/05/map-only-jobs-in-hadoop.html

Comment: Jack: My bad, I read STORED instead SORTED, sorry for that. You are right